# Quick-and-east data visualisation for C#

Tags: c#, matplotlib, geometry, visualization

I need to write some C# code that will do some relatively simple, domain-specific calculations in plane geometry.  I would like a quick-and-dirty way to visualise my results.  For example, if the code was Python, I would import it and some helper functions into an IPython command line and draw things using Matplotlib.

Is there some similarly quick-and-easy solution for looking at the results of C# code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302741/how-do-i-draw-simple-graphics-in-c

Comment: There is no *standard* control like this. Most convenient would be to create own control to visualize data you need (will it be array of points, figures, whatever). In winforms it's basically as simple as creating new class, based on `Control` and overriding `OnPaint`. Then by providing set or methods, properties and subclasses (to hold figures) you can assign data to visualize. In wpf there is `Canvas`.